# SwiftUI TabView Animation Not giving any animation

Tags: swiftui, tabview

I'm trying to create a TabView Slider in SwiftUI with 3 modals that will onboard a user. The default PageTabViewStyle() is a little basic and I'm wanting it to animate with the default slide speed etc.

I've tried appending animation along with the transition from what I've seen online including StackOverflow but it doesn't work.

Here's what I currently have:

```
ZStack {
        Color.black
        TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
                ForEach(OnboardingData.list) { viewData in
                    OnboardingModal(data: viewData)
                        .tag(viewData.id)
                }
           }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .animation(.easeInOut)
            .transition(.slide)
    }
```

Comment: Whatever calls that view, or displays it, should be surrounded with `withAnimation { callView() }`

Comment: From what I've seen you cannot customize the animation/transition using `PageTabViewStyle` on SwiftUI as of iOS 14 (I haven't tried on 15)

Comment: @LuisAscorbe is correct, customization also doesn't work on iOS15.

Comment: Duplicate of [SwiftUI: How to animate a TabView selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61827496/swiftui-how-to-animate-a-tabview-selection)