# SwiftUI bi-directional move transition moving the wrong way in certain cases

Tags: ios, swiftui, transition

I have four main functional areas of my app that can be accessed by the user via a custom tab bar at the bottom of the the ContentView.  I want to use a slide transition to move between the views when the user taps the desired function in the tab bar.

I also want the direction of the slide to be based on the relative position of the options on the tab bar.  That is, if going from tab 1 to tab 3, the views will slide from right to left, or if going from tab 3 to tab 2, the views will slide from left to right.

This works perfectly on the first change of view and for any subsequent change of view that *changes direction of the slide*.  E.g., the following sequence of view changes work:  1->3, 3->2, 2->4, 4->1.

However, *any time there is a change of view where the direction is the same as the previous direction, it doesn't work correctly*.  E.g., the bolded changes in the following sequence don't work properly.  1->2, **2->3**, **3->4**, 4->3, **3->2**.

In the above-mentioned transitions that don't work properly, the incoming view enters from the appropriate direction, but the outgoing view departs in the wrong direction.  For example, the image at the bottom of this post shows the new view moving in appropriately from right to left, but the departing view is moving from **left to right**, leaving the white space on the left (it should also be moving from right to left along with the incoming view).

Any thoughts on why this might be happening / how to correct it?

I'm using iOS 16 for my app.

**Following is a complete code sample demonstrating this issue:**

```
import SwiftUI

@main

struct TabBar_testingApp: App {
    @StateObject var tabOption = TabOption()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(tabOption)
        }
    }
}



class TabOption: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tab: TabItem = .tab1
    @Published var slideLeft: Bool = true
}



enum TabItem: Int, CaseIterable {
    
    // MARK: These are the four main elements of the app that are navigated to via the custom tab or sidebar controls
    
    case tab1 = 0
    case tab2 = 1
    case tab3 = 2
    case tab4 = 3
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .tab1: return "Tab 1"
        case .tab2: return "Tab 2"
        case .tab3: return "Tab 3"
        case .tab4: return "Tab 4"
        }
    }
    
    var icon: String {
        switch self {
        case .tab1: return "1.circle"
        case .tab2: return "2.circle"
        case .tab3: return "3.circle"
        case .tab4: return "4.circle"
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tabOption: TabOption
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                
                // Content
                
                Group {
                    switch tabOption.tab {
                    case TabItem.tab1:
                         SlideOneView()
                    case TabItem.tab2:
                         SlideTwoView()
                    case TabItem.tab3:
                         Slide3View()
                    case TabItem.tab4:
                         SlideFourView()
                    }
                }

                // Use a slide transition when changing the tab views
                .transition(.move(edge: tabOption.slideLeft ? .leading : .trailing))
                                
                Spacer()
                
                // Custom tab bar

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    // Open tab 1
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            // Set the direction the tabs will slide when transitioning between the tabs
                            tabOption.slideLeft = true
                            
                            // Change to the selected tab
                            tabOption.tab = TabItem.tab1
                        }
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: TabItem.tab1.icon).font(.title2)
                            Text(TabItem.tab1.description).font(.caption2)
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(tabOption.tab == .tab1 ? .primary : .secondary)
                        .font(.title)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    // Open tab 2
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            // Set the direction the tabs will slide when transitioning between the tabs
                            if tabOption.tab.rawValue == TabItem.tab1.rawValue {
                                tabOption.slideLeft = false
                            } else {
                                tabOption.slideLeft = true
                            }
                            
                            // Change to the selected tab
                            tabOption.tab = TabItem.tab2
                        }
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: TabItem.tab2.icon).font(.title2)
                            Text(TabItem.tab2.description).font(.caption2)
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(tabOption.tab == .tab2 ? .primary : .secondary)
                        .font(.title)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    // Open tab 3
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            // Set the direction the tabs will slide when transitioning between the tabs
                            if tabOption.tab.rawValue == TabItem.tab4.rawValue {
                                tabOption.slideLeft = true
                            } else {
                                tabOption.slideLeft = false
                            }
                            
                            // Change to the selected tab
                            tabOption.tab = TabItem.tab3
                        }
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: TabItem.tab3.icon).font(.title2)
                            Text(TabItem.tab3.description).font(.caption2)
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(tabOption.tab == .tab3 ? .primary : .secondary)
                        .font(.title)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    
                    // Open tab 4
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            // Set the direction the tabs will slide when transitioning between the tabs
                            tabOption.slideLeft = false
                            
                            // Change to the selected tab
                            tabOption.tab = TabItem.tab4
                        }
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: TabItem.tab4.icon).font(.title2)
                            Text(TabItem.tab4.description).font(.caption2)
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(tabOption.tab == .tab4 ? .primary : .secondary)
                        .font(.title)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                }  // HStack closure
                .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                .padding(.top, 5)
            }
        } 
    }
}



struct SlideOneView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Group {
                Color.blue
                Text("Tab Content 1")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}



struct SlideTwoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Group {
                Color.green
                Text("Tab Content 2")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}



struct Slide3View: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Group {
                Color.purple
                Text("Tab Content 3")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}



struct SlideFourView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Group {
                Color.red
                Text("Tab Content 4")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here's the screenshot where the bottom (departing) view is moving incorrectly from left to right which briefly leaves white space on the left, while the incoming view is correctly moving from right to left.

[image]

HERE'S MY REVISED CODE PER COMMENTS BELOW:

```
class TabOption: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tab: TabItem = .tab1
    @Published var slideLeft: Bool = true
    
    func changeTab(to newTab: TabItem) {
            switch newTab.rawValue {
            // case let allows you to make a comparison in the case statement
            // This determines the direction is decreasing, so we want a right slide
            case let t where t < tab.rawValue:
                slideLeft = false
            // This determines the direction is increasing, so we want a left slide
            case let t where t > tab.rawValue:
                slideLeft = true
            // This determines that the user tapped this tab, so do nothing
            default:
                return
            }
            // We have determined the proper direction, so change tabs.
            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                tab = newTab
            }
        }
}

enum TabItem: Int, CaseIterable {
    
    // MARK: These are the four main elements of the app that are navigated to via the custom tab or sidebar controls
    
    case tab1 = 0
    case tab2 = 1
    case tab3 = 2
    case tab4 = 3
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .tab1: return "Tab 1"
        case .tab2: return "Tab 2"
        case .tab3: return "Tab 3"
        case .tab4: return "Tab 4"
        }
    }
    
    var icon: String {
        switch self {
        case .tab1: return "1.circle"
        case .tab2: return "2.circle"
        case .tab3: return "3.circle"
        case .tab4: return "4.circle"
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tabOption: TabOption
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                
                // Content
                
                Group {
                    switch tabOption.tab {
                    case TabItem.tab1:
                         SlideOneView()
                    case TabItem.tab2:
                         SlideTwoView()
                    case TabItem.tab3:
                         Slide3View()
                    case TabItem.tab4:
                         SlideFourView()
                    }
                }

                // Use a slide transition when changing the tab views
                .transition(
                    .asymmetric(
                        insertion: .move(edge: tabOption.slideLeft ? .trailing : .leading),
                        removal: .move(edge: tabOption.slideLeft ? .leading : .trailing)
                    )
                )
                                
                Spacer()
                
                // Custom tab bar

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    // Open tab 1
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            tabOption.changeTab(to: .tab1)
                        }
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: TabItem.tab1.icon).font(.title2)
                            Text(TabItem.tab1.description).font(.caption2)
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(tabOption.tab == .tab1 ? .primary : .secondary)
                        .font(.title)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    // Open tab 2
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            tabOption.changeTab(to: .tab2)
                        }
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: TabItem.tab2.icon).font(.title2)
                            Text(TabItem.tab2.description).font(.caption2)
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(tabOption.tab == .tab2 ? .primary : .secondary)
                        .font(.title)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    // Open tab 3
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            tabOption.changeTab(to: .tab3)
                        }
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: TabItem.tab3.icon).font(.title2)
                            Text(TabItem.tab3.description).font(.caption2)
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(tabOption.tab == .tab3 ? .primary : .secondary)
                        .font(.title)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    
                    // Open tab 4
                    Button(action: {
                        tabOption.changeTab(to: .tab4)
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: TabItem.tab4.icon).font(.title2)
                            Text(TabItem.tab4.description).font(.caption2)
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(tabOption.tab == .tab4 ? .primary : .secondary)
                        .font(.title)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                }  // HStack closure
                .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                .padding(.top, 5)
            }
      
        } 
    }
}
```

Here's a GIF of the issue using the revised code (apologies for the gif compression "squashing" the screen image, but you get the idea):

[image]

Comment: The really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No one is going to want to recreate all of the missing code to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Yrb.  I replaced my code snippets with a full MRE (or at least somewhat minimal...) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common UX requirement, but very difficult to get right.

In your case, you are trying to have all panels owned by the same parent and to modify the transition edge according to the latest selection. I tried to do it this way too, but here is what I discovered:

1. The edges seem to work differently in iOS 16 compared to iOS 14/15, at least for removal cases.
2. In iOS 16 (at least), I suspect that the edge for the removal transition is already defined at time of insertion. This means, trying to make the edge depend on state values that can change after the view is showing doesn't work.
3. Therefore, to get the edge correct for the removal transition, you need to know which way the user is going to go next. For the first and last panels, this is easy because there is only one way to go, but for the middle panels you have to guess / predict it.
4. If you are not able to predict the next direction of movement correctly every time, then it will never work correctly every time for the middle panels if all the panels share the same parent.

However, there is a way to solve it. This is to make the overall view more hierarchical and to build it up as pairs. I have tested the following with iOS 14, 15, and 16 and it works reliably on all.

```swift
import SwiftUI

/// An enum to describe the possible tab selections
enum TabItem: Int, CaseIterable, Comparable {

    case tab1 = 0
    case tab2 = 1
    case tab3 = 2
    case tab4 = 3

    var description: String {
        "Tab \(self.rawValue + 1)"
    }

    var icon: String {
        "\(self.rawValue + 1).circle"
    }

    static func < (lhs: TabItem, rhs: TabItem) -> Bool {
        lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}

/// View modifier that applies a move transition on the leading edge
struct TransitionLeading: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            content.transition(.move(edge: .leading))
        } else {
            content.transition(
                .asymmetric(
                    insertion: .move(edge: .leading),
                    removal: .move(edge: .trailing)
                )
            )
        }
    }
}

/// View modifier that applies a move transition on the trailing edge
struct TransitionTrailing: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            content.transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        } else {
            content.transition(
                .asymmetric(
                    insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
                    removal: .move(edge: .leading)
                )
            )
        }
    }
}

/// A container for two alternative display panels
struct PanelPair<TabType: Comparable, LeftContent: View, RightContent: View>: View {

    /// The identifier for the left panel
    private let leftTab: TabType

    /// Function that delivers the content for the left panel
    private let leftContent: () -> LeftContent

    /// Function that delivers the content for the right panel
    private let rightContent: () -> RightContent

    /// Read-only value of the state variable that controls the panel selection
    private let selectedTab: TabType

    /// Creates a container for two alternative views
    init(
        leftTab: TabType,
        selectedTab: TabType,
        leftContent: @escaping () -> LeftContent,
        rightContent: @escaping () -> RightContent
    ) {
        self.leftTab = leftTab
        self.selectedTab = selectedTab
        self.leftContent = leftContent
        self.rightContent = rightContent
    }

    var body: some View {

        // Important: the alternative content needs to be in a ZStack
        ZStack {
            if selectedTab <= leftTab {
                leftContent()
                    .modifier(TransitionLeading())
            } else {
                rightContent()
                    .modifier(TransitionTrailing())
            }
        }
    }
}

/// Working example
struct ContentView: View {

    /// State variable that controls the panel selection
    @State private var selectedTab = TabItem.tab1

    /// Factory function for a panel relating to a particular tab
    private func panel(tab: TabItem, color: Color) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Tab Content \(tab.rawValue + 1)")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(color)
    }

    /// Callback for a tab button
    private func changeTab(to: TabItem) {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
            selectedTab = to
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            // The panels
            // Panel 1 + others
            PanelPair(
                leftTab: TabItem.tab1,
                selectedTab: selectedTab,
                leftContent: { panel(tab: .tab1, color: .blue) },
                rightContent: {

                    // Panel 2 + others
                    PanelPair(
                        leftTab: TabItem.tab2,
                        selectedTab: selectedTab,
                        leftContent: { panel(tab: .tab2, color: .green) },
                        rightContent: {

                            // Panels 3 + 4
                            PanelPair(
                                leftTab: TabItem.tab3,
                                selectedTab: selectedTab,
                                leftContent: { panel(tab: .tab3, color: .purple) },
                                rightContent: { panel(tab: .tab4, color: .red) }
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
            // The tab buttons
            HStack {
                ForEach(TabItem.allCases, id: \.self) { tabItem in
                    Button(action: { changeTab(to: tabItem) }) {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: tabItem.icon)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                            Text(tabItem.description)
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(selectedTab == tabItem ? .primary : .secondary)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

This works correctly for all transitions, forwards and backwards, including jumps:

[image: Animation]

*Edit notes*

- `PanelPair` updated to use a generic type as the data type (in this example, the enum `TabItem`). This makes re-use easier.
- In a previous incarnation, this solution applied a `.zIndex` to the lower content, to fix an issue with back jumps (such as from 4 to 1). It seems that this fix is not needed if a `PanelPair` is supplied with the value of the current selection as a read-only value, instead of as a `Binding`. Example updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Benzy. This is amazing. The caveat is still problematic since it doesn't doesn't provide an intuitive jump from 4 to 1.  At this point I've gone to plan B - Adding a transitional "splash" view with a bit of animation to make the change in tabs less abrupt and somewhat interesting.  However, this is great work and will hopefully be useful in other applications.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for trying it @corleyq. Your reply got me thinking more about the back jumps. I managed to find a solution using zIndex on the last ```PanelPair```. I updated the code above, which now works flawlessly (I think), and took out the mention of a caveat in the notes.

Comment: Agreed - The latest code works flawlessly. Thanks again!

Comment: Found a better way to fix the issue of back jumps - answer updated. The edit notes at the bottom describe the changes.

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of things. First, you had way too much logic in your view code.  Remember the DRY principal(Don't Repeat Yourself). Essentially, you are using `TabOption`, so your logic should go in there. I added a function to `TabOption` that contains all the logic to change tabs:

```
class TabOption: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tab: TabItem = .tab1
    @Published var slideLeft: Bool = true
    
    func changeTab(to newTab: TabItem) {
        switch newTab.rawValue {
        // case let allows you to make a comparison in the case statement
        // This determines the direction is decreasing, so we want a right slide
        case let t where t < tab.rawValue:
            slideLeft = false
        // This determines the direction is increasing, so we want a left slide
        case let t where t > tab.rawValue:
            slideLeft = true
        // This determines that the user tapped this tab, so do nothing
        default:
            return
        }
        // We have determined the proper direction, so change tabs.
        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
            tab = newTab
        }
    }
}
```

With that in place, things are easier to reason. In the end, the views were not sliding in the directions you expected because you didn't realize you were dealing with two views that you wanted to do different things with. If you have a slide left, you want the original view to exit by moving its trailing edge, and the new view moving its leading edge. The right slide is reversed. Your transition was telling them to enter and exit from the same direction. What you want is an `.asymmetric()` transition like this:

```
.transition(
    .asymmetric(
        insertion: .move(edge: tabOption.slideLeft ? .trailing : .leading),
        removal: .move(edge: tabOption.slideLeft ? .leading : .trailing)
    )
)
```

Lastly, to complete this, each of your button actions are simply like this:

```
// Open tab 1
Button(action: {
    tabOption.changeTab(to: .tab1)
}) {
    ...
}
```

Edit:

Using the code provided, this is the result following your comments:

[image]

As you can see, there are no issues. Please make sure you adopted all of my code, and not just the asymmetric transition. I am not sure that having the `tabOption.slideLeft = true` inside the animation block is not also causing problems.

Comment: Hi Yrb - Thanks for the feedback and time on this.  The new code now works perfectly when moving in the same direction, but using the asymmetric transition reverses the original problem.  That is, the problem now occurs when you change direction.  As such the bolded transitions in the following sequence now exhibit the problem:  1->2, 2->3, 3->4, **4->3**, 3->2, **2->3**, **3->2**, 2->1, **1->3**, 3->4.  I don't understand why the direction of the tab change in relation to the direction of the previous tab change creates an issue.

Comment: I added a GIF to my answer as to the output of my code. I can't duplicate your issues. If you didn't change all of the code to the recommended code, you could be having an issue with having all changes in the animation block. You also may be having issues with the simulator caching your old code. That seems to happen on Xcode 14 on rare occasions.

Comment: Very strange.  I tried it on my actual device to see if this was the simulator caching issue, but I had the same issue there.  I'm sure I misinterpreted something in your answer when I implemented it, but for the life of me I can't see what it is.  I added the code revisions to the original question.

Comment: Did you try the exact minimal reproducible example, or did you incorporate it into the app?

Comment: For purposes of this issue, I've been working with the exact MRE provided here, using the code changes noted above.  I added my own GIF to show the issue (apologies for the "squashed" gif compression).