# Sync matchedGeometryEffect with slide transition in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I have to implement a slide animation between different cards (steps) for my onboarding screen. Each card has its own background view (circle in my example) that should be synced between all cards' backgrounds into a single animation. For achieving this I'm using the `matchedGeometryEffect`:

```swift
struct OnboardingView: View {

    @Namespace var animation
    @State var step = 1

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Color.background
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .overlay {
                    if step == 1 {
                        ZStack {
                            Color.clear

                            Circle()
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "circle", in: animation)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .offset(x: 50, y: 250)

                            Text("Step 1")
                        }
                        .transition(.asymmetric(
                            insertion: .move(edge: .leading),
                            removal: .move(edge: .leading)
                        ))
                    } else {
                        ZStack {
                            Color.clear

                            Circle()
                                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "circle", in: animation)
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                .offset(x: 50, y: -50)

                            Text("Step 2")
                        }
                        .transition(.asymmetric(
                            insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
                            removal: .move(edge: .trailing)
                        ))
                    }
                }
            // Buttons
        }
        .animation(.linear(duration: 1), value: step)
    }
}
```

Looking at the attached gif we see that the circle animation is almost what I need except a strange duplicate animation. Seems like the circle gets animated from both places: current one and new one (after the transition):

[image]

How can we handle this? I managed to fix this problem by moving a card and a background to different layers, but I want to leave it within the same view having the slide transition when a mathingGeometry isn't attached to a circle.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of `matchedGeometryEffect` is to allow the properties of one or more views, such as their position or size, to be dependent on another view. This other view is the *source* for the properties to be matched.

In your example, you do not have a source. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/matchedgeometryeffect(id:in:properties:anchor:issource:)), this means the results are undefined, so it is almost a surprise that the circles meet up at all. Instead of using a source, you are sizing and positioning the circles using a fixed size and offset. And because each of the alternative views in your example has its own `Circle` , this is why you see 2 circles during a transition.

To solve the multi-circle issue, you should probably have just one circle as a separate layer in the `ZStack`. The position of this circle will depend on the current step. If you were to identify a source view that the circle should track then you could use `matchedGeometryEffect` to control the circle's position. However, your question talks about cards and it sounds like there is only one card visible at a time, so it might be simpler if you just apply an offset like you were doing before. Something like this:

```swift
struct OnboardingView: View {

    @State var step = 1

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .frame(width: step == 1 ? 100 : 50, height: step == 1 ? 100 : 50)
                .offset(x: 50, y: step == 1 ? 250 : -50)
            if step == 1 {
                Text("Step 1")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
            } else {
                Text("Step 2")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            }
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Button("Prev") { step = 1 }
                    Button("Next") { step = 2 }
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .animation(.linear(duration: 1), value: step)
    }
}
```

Ps. If you have a lot of steps in your process and are having difficulty getting the slide transitions to work consistently then you might find it useful to see [SwiftUI bi-directional move transition moving the wrong way in certain cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75806791).